# nested ajax doesn't work for Safari

Tags: jquery, ajax, safari

I put a ajax code into another one, and hope the nested ajax code can be called after its parent ajax code has been finished. As the code shows, it should be able to show "1" first and then "2". It works fine for Chrome, but for Safari, it only does first part.

```
 $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"...",
        success:function(){
            alert("1");
            $this.parent().attr("action","...");
            $this.parent().submit();
            $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url:"...",
                    success:function(){
                         alert("2");       
                    }
            })
        }
    });
```

---

var $cid = index_sr;

```
$(this).children(".comment").children(".options_bar").children(".reply").on("click",function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().children(".reply_container").children(".reply_form").children(".reply_button").on("click",function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            context:$this,
            url:"/yyqGS/public/form/get_clicked_index.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{index:'-1' ,index2:$cid},
            success:function () {
                //alert("1");
                //var $this = $(this);
                $this.parent().attr("action","/yyqGS/public/form/reply.php?c_id=" + $cid);
                $this.parent().submit();


                $.ajax({
                    url:"/yyqGS/public/form/get_url.php",
                    type:"GET",
                    success:function (d1) {
                        alert("1");
                        var $data = d1.split(",");
                        location.href = "/yyqGS/public/form/reply_notification2.php?id="+$data[0]+"&country="+$data[1]+"&tid="+$data[2]+"&cid="+$data[3]+"&rid="+$data[4]+"&cuser="+$data[5];

                    },
                    fail:function () {
                        alert("f");
                    }
                })
            }
        })

    });
});
```

---

I understand what the problem it is now. Since there are 2 ajax, and they go to different php page when success function called. So once one of the success function is called, it will go to that php page, and the rest of jQuery will never be called again!

Wondering how to I fix that problem?

Comment: Is page reloading due to  form? Have you added error handlers to the ajax? Or inspected requests in browser dev tools network?

Comment: @charlietfl so i do
 $this.parent().attr("action","/yyqGS/public/form/reply.php?c_id=" + $cid);
 $this.parent().submit();
in first success function.

Comment: Are you preventing the default submit process on the form? Show all relevant code

Comment: @charlietfl i tried, but still doesn't work. it should work, cuz it works one for Chrome.

Comment: is page reloading due to form?

Comment: @charlietfl yes, i think so

Comment: You need to prevent the form submit `$('.formClassName').on('submit', function(event){ event.preventDefault();})`

Comment: @charlietfl  but if form submission is prevented, how do i submit again afterwards?